# The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am doing a CRUD application using python and aws.

python file:

```
if count == 0:
        response = table.put_item(
                                    Item={
                                            'grow_template_id':str(uuid.uuid4()),
                                            'grow_template_title':str(grow_template_title),
                                            'search_growth_template_title':str(grow_template_title.lower()),
                                            'facility_id':str(facility_id),
                                            'organization_id':str(organization_id),
                                            'actions_to_render':actions_to_render,
                                            'crop_id': str(crop_id),
                                            'task_category_id':str(task_category_id),
      if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            returnvals['status']=1
            returnvals['message']=grow_template_title+" growth template created successfully"
else:
     returnvals['status']=1
     response = table.update_item(
                                     Key={
                                'grow_template_id': str(grow_template_id)
                            },UpdateExpression='SET grow_template_title = :gtt,\
                                                    organization_id = :oid,\
                                                    crop_id = :ci,\
                                                    crop_type = :ct,\
                                                    task_category_id = :tcid,\
                            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                                ":gtt":grow_template_title,
                                ":oid":organization_id,
                                ":ci":crop_id,
                                ":ct":crop_type,
                                ":tcid":task_category_id,
```

When i click on submit,  i am getting a bug like this:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) 
when calling the UpdateItem operation: 
One or more parameter values are not valid. 
The AttributeValue for a key attribute cannot contain an empty string value.
 Key: grow_template_id"
```

What mistake i am doing?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: What is your `grow_template_id`?